# Fetching more than id's of an entity using EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database

I have just learnt how to use the EntityFieldQuery to make simple queries.

In the example below I fetch all the comment id's for the logged-in-user.

```
global $user;

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'comment')
->propertyCondition('uid', $user->uid)
->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));
$result = $query->execute();
var_dump($result);
$cids = array();
if (isset($result['comment']))
$cids = array_keys($result['comment']);
```

> Is it possible to get the **comment body** and the **node id** where that
>   comment belongs using the way i use above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you need to load the comment (`comment_load()`) to get property and field data attached to the results of an EFQ - its job is to load IDs only.

An alternative would be mikeytown2's [EntityFieldQueryExtra](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mikeytown2/2209909) class, which does allow you to attach field and property data to the results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a type of entity you have to add the entity_type condition to it.

You have to fetch nodes, so the code for it will be as follows:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
```

The entity condition is set using the function **entityCondition** in which you can set the entity type as node. Once if you have set the entity condition, you can execute the query. The **node ids** are returned in an array in the node key of the result. The complete code to display the nodes will be as follows:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');


    $result = $query->execute();
    $nodes = array();
    if (isset($result['node'])) {
      $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
      $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    }

    $list = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
      $url = url('node/' . $node->nid, $options);
      $list[] = '<a href='.$url.'>'.$node->title.'</a>';
    }

    $theme_args = array('items' => $list, 'type' => 'ol');
    $content = theme('item_list', $theme_args);

    $block = array(
      'subject' => t('A block to display results from entityquery'),
      'content' => $content,
    );
    return $block;
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is completely wrong - the OP is asking how to load comment entities, there's no mention of nodes.

Comment: You've lost me - the question is _Is it possible to get the comment body and the node id where that comment belongs using the way i use above?_. The answer is no, it doesn't involve loading nodes

Comment: How could you say that this answer is completely wrong?
I took this question when I saw the title "Fetching more than id's of an entity using EntityFieldQuery". Was I true about it? And now the body: if the answer explains the basic rule-then why not comment and comment body?

I don't think anyone here seeks for their first attempt in D7(esp. when trying entities). If you think it was not directly meant to the question, let me bow, I am very sorry.

Comment: No need to apologise, your opinion is just as valid as mine :) I just don't think this addresses the specific question that was asked

Comment: That was a mis-edit. Really sorry. :) Have a nice day.